# grouping values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKh7l.png)

and I want to group similar item column values

without using the groupby().agg()  function, as don't want to perform any arithmetic operation on the price column

I am looking to make this DataFrame

into something like this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then below answer can use to get your desired results by using `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index=['item','date'],values='price')
```

**Where:**

**df** = your dataframe

Kindly check and let me know if its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

You can use `set_index`:

```
df = df.set_index(['item','date'])
```